# Фантазия с CSS

Tags: css

Требуется сделать фон для сайта - плавно перетекающий цвет от черного к белому (черный на верху а белый внизу) и по середине находится сама непосредственно страница с информацией). Это делается в css или просто фоновая картинка используется?

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать фоновую картинку. Но при этом высота контента должна быть фиксированной. Лучше применить [градиент](http://gradients.glrzad.com/)

```
background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(255,255,255) 13%, rgb(20,19,20) 57%, rgb(240,226,234) 0%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(255,255,255) 13%, rgb(20,19,20) 57%, rgb(240,226,234) 0%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(255,255,255) 13%, rgb(20,19,20) 57%, rgb(240,226,234) 0%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(255,255,255) 13%, rgb(20,19,20) 57%, rgb(240,226,234) 0%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(255,255,255) 13%, rgb(20,19,20) 57%, rgb(240,226,234) 0%);

background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(0.13, rgb(255,255,255)),
    color-stop(0.57, rgb(20,19,20)),
    color-stop(0, rgb(240,226,234))
);
```

Comment: PS:CSS3, если надо с IE и т.д. - делайте картинкой...

Comment: Так картинкой или нет? А как картинку такую нарисовать чтоб были соблюдены пропорции и плавность?

Comment: PhotoShop в помощь...<br>
Под современные браузеры решение предложенное <b>shuric'ом</b> абсолютно нормальное...

Comment: Для IE следует применить такую запись:

 filter:     progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ffffffff, endColorstr=#0000000);

Comment: да но выглядит это ИМХО неочень...

Comment: я делаю градиент в 3 захода использую условные комменты для ie
1.для ie 7 и 8 (через PIE)
2.для ie 9 (через filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient)
3.для moz, webkit, o

когда разделяются эти стили filter для ie очень даже не плохо себя ведет